# Linq query, how to check for a null value and use the value 0 in place of a null?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query:

```
var ordersPlacedBeforeOneHourList = ordersPlacedBeforeOneHourAgo.Select(order => order.Promo.PercentOff * (double) order.TotalCost).ToList();
```

Some of my `order.Promo.PercentOff` are null.  How can I change the above line so that if `order.Promo` is null, it behaves as if the values is `0`?

The idea is that if there is not a specific promotion applied, I will calculate the cost of the Promotion as `0 * order.TotalCost` (which will always be 0), and move on to the next values to calculate where `orders.Promo` may not be null, and on down the line.

Comment: I think there's a case to be made for changing the schema and using `0` instead of `null` in the database. What does `null` mean? That you don't know how much to shave off the price? Obviously not.

Comment: Indeed. Adding `NOT NULL DEFAULT 0` to that column would be a big improvement.

Comment: Order.Promo is a virtual field that is referenced through entity framework by id (Order.PromoId) -- I'm not sure how I would make that return a default of 0.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) is your friend.

```
(order.Promo.PercentOff ?? 0)
```